# How to organize redirects which depends commit value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Consider a blog application, with a form to create new posts. There are two buttons, "Save", "Save and continue editing", which would redirect the user accordingly after save.

This is the code:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    if params[:commit] == "Create & continue editing"
      redirect_to edit_admin_post_path(@post), :notice => "Post record has been created"
    else
      redirect_to admin_posts_path, :notice => "Post record has been created"
    end
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Post record has some validation errors"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Is this the best way to do this, or is there some other way to refactor this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

in view:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Save', name: 'save' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Save and continue editing', name: 'save_and_edit' %>
```

in controller:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to(params[:commit] == 'save' ? admin_posts_path : edit_admin_post_path(@post), notice: "Post record has been created")
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Post record has some validation errors"
    render :new
  end
end
```